# Expect: Prompt extending to next line

Tags: shell, expect

I am trying to install a software which is a shell script file. I am using **expect** to do the silent installation.

There is a strange line during the installation of the software where the prompt goes to the next line like this below.

```
ENTER AN ABSOLUTE PATH, OR PRESS <ENTER> TO ACCEPT THE DEFAULT 
  :
```

So I have tried with these 2 options, but it's NOT working!

```
1. expect  "    : " { send "/home/tester/IDir\r" }
2. expect "ENTER AN ABSOLUTE PATH, OR PRESS <ENTER> TO ACCEPT THE DEFAULT\
      : " { send "/home/tester/IDir\r" }
```

---

**Expect File**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#Taking arguments from test.sh file

set File [lindex $argv 0]
set IDir [lindex $argv 1]
spawn sh /home/tester/$File 
expect "PRESS <ENTER> TO CONTINUE: " { send "\n" }
exp_internal 1
expect -re "TO ACCEPT THE DEFAULT\r\n.*?:" { send "/home/tester/IDir\r" }
#expect "      : " { send "/home/tester/IDir\r" }
expect "IS THIS CORRECT? (Y/N): " { send "Y\n" }
expect "PRESS <ENTER> TO CONTINUE: " { send "\n" }
sleep 2
expect "ENTER THE NUMBER OF THE DESIRED CHOICE: " { send "2\n" }
expect "PRESS <ENTER> TO EXIT THE INSTALLER: " { send "\n" }
sleep 2
expect eof
```

---

**test.sh file**

```
dir=James/SDD
cd /home/tester
file=`ls | grep xx_yy*_linux_x86-64.bin`
expect script.exp $file $dir
```

---

Comment: Can you add `exp_internal 1`  just before the `expect` command and share the debug output ?

Comment: @Dinesh, I have added the debug logs above. Please check. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing the logs, realized that your `expect` code is getting timed out for most of the cases.

```
# This timeout is meant for the first expect word 'PRESS <ENTER> TO CONTINUE', so it is proceeding to the next expect word 'TO ACCEPT THE DEFAULT.*?:' 
expect: timed out
Gate keeper glob pattern for 'TO ACCEPT THE DEFAULT
.*?: ' is 'TO ACCEPT THE DEFAULT
```

You need to add the proper timeout handling for the `expect` statement. Default timeout is 10 seconds. You can change it in a way as follows,

```
set timeout 120; # Now, timeout value is 2 min
```

I can see that you have used `sleep` in some places, in the same way, do that for earlier expect commands as well. (Using `timeout` would be better in such cases than sleeping.)

```
#Taking arguments from test.sh file
set File [lindex $argv 0]
set IDir [lindex $argv 1]

# A common handler for timeout. 
# Customize it as per your need.
proc my_timeout_handler {} {
    puts "Timeout happened :("
    exit 1
}

spawn sh /home/tester/$File 
set timeout 300; # 5 mins.
expect {
    "PRESS <ENTER> TO CONTINUE: " { send "\n" }
    timeout {my_timeout_handler}
}
expect {
    -re "TO ACCEPT THE DEFAULT\r\n.*?:" { send "/home/tester/IDir\r" }
    timeout {my_timeout_handler}
}    
expect {
    "IS THIS CORRECT? (Y/N): " { send "Y\r" }
    timeout {my_timeout_handler}
}
expect {
    "PRESS <ENTER> TO CONTINUE: " { send "\r" }
    timeout {my_timeout_handler}
}
expect {
    "ENTER THE NUMBER OF THE DESIRED CHOICE: " { send "2\r" }
    timeout {my_timeout_handler}
}
expect {
    "PRESS <ENTER> TO EXIT THE INSTALLER: " { send "\r" }
    timeout {my_timeout_handler}
}
expect {
    eof {puts "Program completed"}
    timeout {my_timeout_handler}
}
```

Comment: If problem is still there, it would be better if you post the full code.

Comment: Dinesh, still getting the same time out . I have copied the files above.

Comment: @BVenky :  Place the `exp_internal 1` at the first line of code and update the debug info.

Comment: Awesome!! It worked really well and fast! Thanks a lot for your help, appreciate it.